# Positional write to existing file [Linux, NodeJS]

Tags: node.js, file-io

I'm trying to edit an existing binary file using NodeJS.

My code goes something like this:

```
file = fs.createWriteStream("/path/to/existing/binary/file", {flags: "a"});
file.pos = 256;
file.write(new Buffer([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

In OS X, this works as expected (The bytes at `256..261` get replaced with `0..5`).

In linux however, the 5 bytes get appended to the end of file. This is also mentioned in the [NodeJS API Reference](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback):

> On Linux, positional writes don't work when the file is opened in append mode. The kernel ignores the position argument and always appends the data to the end of the file.

How do I get around this?

Comment: I'm new to node and I'm just curious, for what reason would you want to do this, " editing of a binary?". I know this is question ception but what is the end result and what does this solve?

Comment: Well, I need to download a file using multiple connections (like a download manager). So when the process gets terminated, I don't only append to the entire file, I "append" to all the chunks within the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open with a mode of `r+` instead of `a`. `r+` is the portable way to say that you want to read and/or write to arbitrary positions in the file, and that the file should already exist.

Comment: Guess the actual question was regarding the file access modes.

Comment: Doesn't this *replace* from the provided position instead of appending to the content?

Comment: @greduan yes, and that appears to be what the question was asking for :)

Comment: Ah OK. I assumed he wanted to append because he quoted that Linux edge-case/bug/feature about append flags.